# Select where in list or else select all most elegantly

Tags: sql, sql-server, list, where-clause, list-comparison

For a select statement I set a part of the where condition externally in a configuration file as parameter, like this (`COL2` is filled with string values):

```
SELECT COL1
      ,COL2
FROM TABLE1
WHERE COL2 = $external_parameter
```

Now I have a more complex case, where I need the external parameter to be a list. Whenever a value of `COL2` is in the list, it should select, however if no list is provided or some kind of "empty" tag, every value should be selected again. I came up with an idea, but it does not work that way:

```
SELECT COL1
      ,COL2
FROM TABLE1
WHERE $external_list = ('') or COL2 IN $external_list
```

Like this, the statement would be true for all elements of `COL2` when an empty list is provided, and true for every element in the list that matches with the list if a filled list is provided.

However, if I provide a filled list it will not work on the comparison in the first half of the where statement:

```
('entry_a', 'entry_b') = ('')
```

Is there any query that would make it work - best in a one line where statement?

Comment: All answers provided do not work for my as I provide a list as external parameter, so it always comes to `('entry_a', 'entry_b') = ''`, which does not seem to work for me. Do I need to provide the list in the external parameter in a different format?

Comment: `WHERE '' IN $external_list OR COL2 IN $external_list`

Comment: This is the most elegant thing that works on my case, I guess I will use it. But it does not cover the case that somebody accidentally sets the list to `('entry_a', 'entry_b','')`. I need to find a check for that. But it will work for me I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
SELECT COL1
    ,COL2
FROM TABLE1
WHERE COL2 IN ($EXTERNAL_PARAMETER)
    OR 1 = (
        CASE 
            WHEN $EXTERNAL_PARAMETER = ''
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END
        )
```

Comment: The comparison of $EXTERNAL_PARAMETER which is ('entry_a', 'entry_b') with a string '' does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
SELECT COL1
    ,COL2
FROM TABLE1
WHERE COL2 IN (
            CASE 
            WHEN $EXTERNAL_PARAMETER = ''
                THEN COL2 
            ELSE $EXTERNAL_PARAMETER
            END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 IF  $EXTERNAL_PARAMETER = ''
 SET $EXTERNAL_PARAMETER = NULL

SELECT COL1
    ,COL2
FROM TABLE1
WHERE COL2 = ISNULL($EXTERNAL_PARAMETER, COL2 )
```